# Unable to install bower components from bower.json

Tags: javascript, frontend, bower, package-managers

In the folder that contains my bower.JSON I'm running this command **bower install** but the dependencies are not getting installed, also I cannot find any bower_components folder. On running **bower list** I can see that the dependencies are not installed.What should I do?[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using bower?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is write issues in your directory.

Check if your target Directory have write access.

Comment: my .bowerrc looks like this {
  "directory": "app/bower_components"
}

Comment: The bower modules are being installed inside the app folder. And from screen it seems you are running the command on app level. Check inside app folder.